# How to plot groupwise mean with data in R?

Tags: r

I have some data like this:

```
1 1.57722e-18
1 1.57722e-18
1 1.57722e-18
1 2.8422e-11
1 3.96449e-20
1 4.1027e-11
2 1.57722e-18
2 1.57722e-18
2 1.57722e-18
2 2.8422e-11
2 3.96449e-20
2 4.1027e-11
2 4.19834e-17
2 7.62155e-20
3 1.57722e-18
3 1.57722e-18
3 1.57722e-18
3 2.8422e-11
3 3.96449e-20
3 4.1027e-11
3 4.19834e-17
3 7.62155e-20
3 2.00414e-17
```

Here first column = position, second column = probability. I can plot with plot function in R like this

```
dataset = read.table(path, col.names=c("pos", "prob"))
plot(dataset$pos, log10(dataset$prob), type="p", col="red")
```

Now I want to include mean for each position with different color so that it distinguishes in the same graph. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
points(tapply(log10(dataset$prob), dataset$pos, mean), col = "blue")
```

[image]